# Python framework for object-XML mapping through decorators?

Tags: python, xml, serialization, decorator

After coming up impressed with the ease of use of the XML serialization framework [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) XML in Java, I've tried looking for a Python counterpart that would facilitate implementing classes and their XML serialization in a similar fashion. So far, I've come up more or less empty-handed, although there are interesting candidates (but none conveniently using [decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators), as far as I could tell); for example, I started looking at [dexml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dexml/), but I got stumped with an example as simple as implementing a class that would allow deserialization of

```
<Error Code="0">OK</Error>
```

With Simple in Java, I could write a class such as

```
@Root(name="Error")
public class Error {

    @Attribute(name = "Code")
    private int code;  // public getter and setter

    @Text(required = false) 
    private String description; // public getter and setter
}
```

Is there already a similar flavored framework in Python as Simple for Java? I have preference for Python 2.6 support, although that's not mandatory; if it's supported only for Python 3 I'll also look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this syntax is supported in dexml.  It took me awhile to figure it out (reading the source code helped).

```
class Error(dexml.Model):
    code = dexml.fields.String()
    value = dexml.fields.String(tagname=".")
```

And the following will return the xml rendering of desire:

```
e = Error(code="0",value="OK")
print e.render(fragment=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an answer but will confirm the difficulty of using dexml to parse your example. It doesn't look like there is a way to parse an element with attributes and a text node. Defining the Code attribute is simple:

```
class Error(dexml.Model):
    code = dexml.fields.String(attrname="Code")
```

But there is no way to reference a child text node. One would like to do something like:

```
class Error(dexml.Model):
    code = dexml.fields.String(attrname="Code")
    text = dexml.fields.String(textnode=True)
```

One not very satisfactory way to capture the text would be to wrap it in extra tags:

```
<Error Code="0"><text>OK</text></Error>
```

Then you could define the class as:

```
class Error(dexml.Model):
    code = dexml.fields.String(attrname="Code")
    text = dexml.fields.String(tagname="text")
```